# Are There Names for the Sundays in Eastertide?

Tags: liturgical-calendar

I've done some digging and it seems that there may or may not be names for the individual names of the Sunday's in Eastertide. So the question is, are there names for each individual Sunday?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Are There Names for the Sundays in Eastertide?**

The short answer is **yes**. But it will depend on the denomination and century involved as the Catholic Church has actually adapted a new Liturgical Calendar in 1969.

> [Eastertide](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastertide) or Paschaltide is a festal season in the liturgical year of Christianity that focuses on celebrating the Resurrection of Jesus Christ. It begins on Easter Sunday, which initiates Easter Week in Western Christianity, and Bright Week in Eastern Christianity. There are several Eastertide customs across the Christian world, including sunrise services, exclaiming the Paschal greeting, clipping the church, and decorating Easter eggs, a symbol of the empty tomb. The Easter lily, a symbol of the resurrection, traditionally serve as the chancel flowers that decorate the chancel area of churches throughout Eastertide. Other Eastertide customs include egg hunting, eating special Easter foods and watching Easter parades.
>
> The first eight days constitute the Octave of Easter and are celebrated as solemnities of the Lord.

First Sunday of Easter

- Easter Sunday
- Sunday of the Resurrection of Out Lord Jesus Christ

Second Sunday of Easter

- [Divine Mercy Sunday](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_Mercy_Sunday)
- Quasimodo Sunday
- Bright Sunday
- [Low Sunday](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/09400a.htm)
- Sunday *in Albis*
- Antipascha (Eastern Christianity)
- New Sunday
- Renewal Sunday
- Thomas Sunday

Third Sunday of Easter

- Misericordia Sunday
- Good Shepherd Sunday (Extraordinary Form of the Mass)
- Sunday of the Myrrh-bearers (Greek Orthodox Church)

Fourth Sunday of Easter

- Jubilate Sunday
- [Good Shepherd Sunday](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/liturgicalyear/calendar/day.cfm?date=2021-04-25)
- Vocations Sunday
- Sunday of the Paralytic (Greek Orthodoxy)

Fifth Sunday of Easter

- Cantate Sunday (Extraordinary Form of the Mass of the Catholic Church)
- Sunday of the Samaritan Woman (Greek Orthodox)
- Fifth Sunday of Holy Pascha [Greek Orthodox)

Sixth Sunday of Easter

- Sunday of the Man Born Blind (Oriental Churches)
- Ascension of Our Lord Sunday (when transferred as a feast in the Ordinary Form of the Catholic Church)
- [Rogation Sunday](https://www.churchtimes.co.uk/articles/2012/13-july/regulars/out-of-the-question/rogation-sunday-traditions)

Seventh Sunday of Easter

- “Exaudi” Sunday (Extraordinary Form)
- [Sunday of the Roses](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosalia_(festival)#)
- “Second feast of the flowers" (Armenian)

Eighth Sunday of Easter

- Pentecost
- Whit Sunday

Comment: Very interesting and thorough.Just a few points.  I think that in places where the Ascension is transferred from the Thursday it is typically to the following Sunday (i.e. seventh)? The sixth in the British Isles is widely called Rogation Sunday, and  Whit Sunday aka Pentecost is now acording to  the RCC regarded as the last and eighth Sunday of Easter.

Comment: @davidlol Thanks, I made some updates.